# Autofilling new password with confirmation in iOS 12

Tags: uikit, ios12

I've added 3 `UITextFields` to create a new account by entering a username in email address format, a new password and a password confirmation. As suggested in [Enabling Password AutoFill on a Text Input View](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view%20ggg). I have configured the username field like this

```
userTextField.textContentType = .username  
userTextField.keyboardType = .emailAddress
```

and the new password fields like this

```
newPasswordTextField.textContentType = .newPassword  
confirmPasswordTextField.textContentType = .newPassword
```

Now, when the users enters an email address as username the `newPasswordTextField` is pre-filled with a suggestion for a strong password (as expected), but the `confirmPasswordTextField` isn't filled with the same suggested password.
When the user directly taps into the `newPasswordTextField` without entering a username before both `newPasswordTextField` and `confirmPasswordTextField` are pre-filled with the same suggested password (also as suggested).

How can i combine this both situations that after the user enters a username both password fields will be pre-filled with the same password?

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue and starting to bash my head against the walls. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Same problem here. Has anyone found a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to do autocomplete for 2 password fields by declaring the `contentType` of the first field as: `.password`

1. `.username`
2. `.password`
3. `.newPassword`

Comment: note: it really have to be in that order of .password and .newPassword

Comment: Actually, it seems to works if only the confirmation field is set with `textContentType` as `.newPassword`. Just don't set `textContentType` for the first field, or set it to `.none` for example.

Answer (score 3):

**iOS 14 update**

The [answer from cornr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52892154/2439941) worked for iOS 12 and 13.

However, it fails since iOS 14 in our app, as it will now request access to Keychain to auto-fill the stored password.

It seems that per iOS 14 Apple made it finally match their [docu example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view) to create a new account or changing the password. This means that for both password fields `.newPassword` should be used.

Having that said, suggesting a strong password **fails entirely** for us on iOS 14.2. For more details see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64663687/cannot-show-automatic-strong-passwords-for-app-bundleid).