# Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords

Tags: ios, autofill, entitlements

Error Message:

```
[AutoFill] Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID: com.AnyPlay due to error: Cannot identify the calling app's process. Check teamID and bundleID in your app's application-identifier entitlement
```

Entitlement looks like this:
[image]

What am I missing in the entitlement? In WWDC 2018 says that associated domains enough to use this feature.

Comment: Could you find a solution? I have the same problem

Comment: I also have that problem

Answer (score 0):

This is an iOS 14 problem apparently - the problem is explained much better elsewhere in StackOverflow and the Apple dev forums:

[Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64663687/cannot-show-automatic-strong-passwords-for-app-bundleid)

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/667405